# Getting PK of updated records in cakephp/sql server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, cakephp, bulkinsert

I have used bulk update to sync datas between two tables as below

```
$sqlProc="
UPDATE cards
SET cards.card_no = t2.card_number,
    cards.expiry_date=t2.expiry_date OUTPUT INSERTED.Id AS 'updated_id'
FROM cards
INNER JOIN card_temp t2 ON (cards.account_no = t2.account_number
                            AND cards.customer_name=t2.customer_name)
WHERE cards.is_disabled='N'";
        debug($this->Request->query($sqlProc));
```

Above query will also return Primary key of updated records using`OUTPUT INSERTED.Id AS 'updated_id'` in sql server editor but when i debug the sql

```
debug($this->Request->query($sqlProc));
```

Then it return `true` for successful query and `false` for unsuccessful query.

Is there any idea to fetch `updated_id` to array , so that i can use those ids to another table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , I figured out finally . I created one intermediate table did the following

```
//inserted into temp_id (bridge table)
$sqlProc="insert into temp_id select * FROM (update cards 
                        set         cards.card_no = t2.card_number,cards.expiry_date=t2.expiry_date
                        OUTPUT INSERTED.Id AS 'updated_id'
                        from        cards 
                        inner join  card_temp t2
                        on          (cards.account_no = t2.account_number and cards.customer_name=t2.customer_name)
                        where cards.is_disabled='N'
                        ) AS t";
        $this->Request->query($sqlProc);
        //fetch from intermediate table

        $sqlSel="SELECT * FROM temp_id";
        $arr=$this->Request->query($sqlSel);
          //this array will fetch all updated id's
        debug($arr);
        $sqlDel="DELETE FROM temp_id";
        $this->Request->query($sqlDel);
```